# Abstract method Overriding, implementing a different return type in java

Tags: java, csv, overriding, abstract-class

I have an abstract Java class `FileManager` that contains three methods for file operations.

1. `openFile()`
2. `abstract readFile()`
3. `closeFile()`

   I want to specify all the three methods inside the class `FileManager`. However, the method `readFile()` will have to read different types of files. viz `csv`, `xls`, `doc`. In future the code may even have to read `PDF` files.

The return type for all such calls will be different.

This means that when I read csv file, I will return an ArrayList , an xls file on the other hand will return a HashMap , and so on.

To accomplish this, and make the code factory compliant , I am planning on making a separate reader class in the project for each fileType. ( `CSVFileReader` , `DOCFileReader` , `XLSFileReader` etc. )

Is there any way  , where I can force the developer to include the `readFile()` method in his ______(CSV/XLS/DOC)Filereader implementation?

PS: Java defines that the overridden method in subclass should have the same or a subtype of return type. My question is how do I specify `readFile()` in the `FileManager` implementation and also have different return type for each of the different types of files?

Comment: Please read the comment I left on the accepted answer. I don't believe this is a good solution, the solution I proposed makes more sense in a OOP point of view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use genericity :

```
public abstract class FileManager<OUPUT> {
    public abstract OUTPUT readFile();
}

public class CSVFileReader extends FileManager<List<String>> {
    @Override
    public List<String> readFile() {
        // ...
    }
}

public class XLSFileReader extends FileManager<Map<String, String>> {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> readFile() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but as someone, unfamiliar with generics (till yet ) , can you please tell what is OUTPUT ??

Comment: It is exactly like the other provided answer. `OUPUT` is just the name of the generic type I have chosen. The other answer chose `T`, this is alright but I prefer giving generic types a semantic when possible

Comment: Ahh...got it..perfect answer, Answers my question exactly. Thank you. :)

Comment: It may solve your problem. But "FileReader IS NOT a FileManager". It doesn't make sense from OOP point of view.

Comment: @RamanShrivastava what ? The OP seems satisfied. The name are not consistent, but I took the names in the question, and I don't think I'm wrong when I say the OP wanted to subclass `FileManager`. Can you tell me, apart from the naming which I did not choose, what does not make sense in an OOP poit of view in this answer ?

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use  as the return type. This will let you pick the return type on the fly.

```
public <T> T mymethod(T type)
{
  return type;
}
```

Here is a brief tutorial about using generic types in java by Oracle.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html

Comment: Cause the question is about a return type in a method. The class part is not relevant. Why don't you suggest another method.

Comment: You do not have to pass an object of a type T. I copy and pasted that example from learning material. You are just trying to steal my points.

Comment: Look at your answer, you are passing a parameter... If you just copy-paste random stuff from the doc without showing how this is useful to the question, this is a bad answer anyway. And I maintain your answer is wrong. Try removing your parameter, put this method on a non-generic abstract class, and implement the method with two different return type in two subclasses. This is impossible, try it. The parent class has to be generic. What you have shown indeed exists but is not relevant in this case